# python why does it call __str__ instead of __repr__ and why is the print(obj) not working and throws exception

Tags: python, string, class, call, repr

I have a litte problem because whenever i run the code print(obj) in the try/except part it throws an exception. i followed it with the debugging tool and it jumps right in the **str** method but i coded the **str** methode just for testing. Normally i thought it would jump in the **repr** method for normal class calls.
The code breaks right in the return command of the **str**() method.
I just wanted to change the output of the time.time_struct class because i need the string and the attribute represenation.
the print commands ar just for displaying the results, the block in the **init** statement works but in the try/Except block it doesnt.
Does anyone have an idea?

```
import time

class timeSelf():

def __init__(self,str):
    self.obj = time.strptime(str, "%H:%M")
    print(self.obj.tm_hour)
    print(type(self.obj))
def __repr__(self):
    return "" + self.obj.tm_hour + ":" + self.obj.tm_min

def __str__(self):
    return "" + self.obj.tm_hour + ":" + self.obj.tm_min

if __name__ == "__main__":
str= "16:54"
try:
    obj = timeSelf(str)
    print(obj)
    print(type(obj))
    print(type(obj.tm_hour))
except Exception:
    print("stuff happened")
    pass
```

Comment: `print` calls `str`, not `repr`.

Comment: If your code is raising an exception, don't ignore it if you don't know what caused it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you hadn't caught the exception (or if you re-raised it to see what you *had* caught), you would see the problem is with your definitions of `__str__` and `__repr__`. You are attempting to combine `int` and `""` values with `+`, and *no* automatic conversion of `int` to `str` occurs there.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tmp.py", line 19, in <module>
    print(obj)
  File "tmp.py", line 13, in __str__
    return "" + self.obj.tm_hour + ":" + self.obj.tm_min
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str
```

You have to be explicit:

```
return "" + str(self.obj.tm_hour) + ":" + str(self.obj.tm_min)
```

or more simply:

```
return f"{self.obj.tm_hour}:{self.obj.tm_min}"
```

f-strings *do* call `__str__` as necessary to convert the value inside `{...}` to a `str`.

Comment: To note: `"" + ...` is pretty darn pointless. Prefixing anything with an empty string does… nothing.